# Bad performance of ResultSet.next() in java sqlite JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a performance issue with `ResultSet.next()` while retrieving data from an sqlite database. I am using **org.sqlite.JDBC** driver. I tried setting up statement/`ResultSet.fetchSize()`, but that did not work either.

The operation lasts around 25 seconds when I use an SQL statement with a string paramater in the `WHERE` clause (with a non-string parameter in the `WHERE`, it lasts just 4 seconds).

I found that with some drivers it is possible to set up `send string parameter as unicode = false` in the URL, which should improve performance. However, I was not able to find way how to set it up with SQLite connection.

Can some one help me with this issue?

Comment: You should add some more information: How much data, how many rows, resultset-row-size, data type, indexes...? What is your expectation on performance?

Comment: Without further information than that, my best *guess* is that you have a huge table and no index on the column used in the `where` clause. But as I said, that's just a *guess*.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, result rows are computed on demand. (SQLite is not a client/server database, so there is no communication overhead.)

So when `next()` is slow, this just means that your query is slow, and that the database must do much I/O and/or many computations until it can return the next row.

To speed it up, you have to improve the database design, or the query, or the hardware.